# Reset DELL iDRAC password without rebooting ESXi

Tags: vmware-esxi, dell-poweredge, drac

For one of our machines we lost our root password for the *iDrac7 Enterprise* interface. The machine is running many virtual machines and turning them off would be a huge task.

So, my question is: Is there a way to reset the iDrac Password **without rebooting** the machine? It's running *VMware ESXi 5.5* and I can connect to it via vSphere client as well as SSH.

Comment: Is this host a member of a vSphere HA cluster?

Comment: No. It's just a single ESXi Essential installation.

Answer (score 7):

Try this from the command line: `racadm racresetcfg`

If you have the DRAC tools installed, it'll reset your DRAC to factory defaults. If it fails, you're stuck rebooting the server.

Comment: No. `racadm` is not installed. Any other idea? (I stopped reading at "If it fails" ;-)

Comment: @EthanLeroy [Um... install it](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/w/wiki/3205.racadm-command-line-interface-for-drac.aspx)?

Comment: It's been a long time since my last comment, but the problem is still there. @HopelessN00b Thanks for the link, but I also have a problem with this: **My operating system is ESXi 5.5** and the download list does not contain the mentioned _Linux Remote Access Utilities_. So, **where can I download the those DRAC Tools for Unix-Systems/ESXi 5.5**?

Comment: @EthanLeroy [This seems to be applicable](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=D0JCN).

Comment: @EthanLeroy On a related note, it's been 9 months, and a new major verion of ESXi is out.  Getting close to reboot time, if for no reason other than to upgrade to a newer version of ESXi.

Comment: OM-DRAC-Dell-Web-WINX64-7.4.0-866_A00.exe I don't think I can install this on my ESXi machine. For upgrading ESXi I need access to DRAC :-)

Comment: Ethan - for heaven's sake, read the whole article. "The Dell Remote Access Controller (DRAC) console is management station software designed to provide remote management capabilities for the Dell systems. " That means you install it on a management station, not the server.

Comment: Ok. But then I don't have the `racadm` command on the machine and (I assume) I won't be able to update the password without providing the current password, right?

Comment: you get the racadm command by installing the DRAC console tools on your windows workstation.

Comment: And it's been like 9 months, as Hopelessnoob said. You could have arranged a reboot during a maintenance window at sometime in the past 9 months.

Comment: Again: My machine runs ESXi 4 and *not* Windows. So, I can take another computer, install it there, but it would be a big security hole if I could then reset my iDRAC password from that machine, because that would mean that anyone could reset it. 
Reboot: For resetting the password during reboot, I need access to the iDRAC interface. So, a reboot won't help me much, as long as I am not on site. Additionally the server hosts dozens of virtual machines so I really like to avoid a reboot.

Comment: Yes, this needs to be installed on ANOTHER MACHINE, like your own desktop. It's a best practice to keep console and other OOB interfaces on a VLAN that's only accessible by IT staff. And if iDRAC is your only method of console management, you are in a bind. If this is in a datacenter and you don't have some other form of remote KVM, send them instructions on how to do this from a crash cart. Regarding the reboot - yes it's inconvenient, but you've had almost a year to schedule it at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm resurrecting the dead here, but here is an "half-answer" for anyone who stumbles across this question.  (I know you've already sorted your issue, and no one wants to reboot their servers if they can help it!)

**You can do this from OpenManage for ESX, but...**

...as it does require a reboot of ESX after install, at least if you pre-install it, and if you have some *unexpected* downtime, when the server comes back up you can have all the access you want, as well as change the iDrac username/password.

Here are [instructions from Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/article/uk/en/ukbsdt1/how10613/how-to-install-openmanage-server-administrator--omsa--on-vmware-to-collect-logs?lang=en), and supports ESX 5.5 to 6.5 - steps 1-6 tell you all you need to know to install OpenManage on ESX, just ignore the last step.

I make it a habit now to install OpenManage on all servers immediately after installing ESX as well as setting up the iDrac, just in case!

(I'm not going to re-post the entire page contents - suffice to say if anyone comments on this that the link is broken, I'll update the link)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:  push and hold down the glowing blue button labelled "i" on the back of the server for 15 seconds...
that will reboot the iDrac.

Comment: The OP asked for a solution which did **not** involve rebooting the machine, just resetting the password...

Comment: This just restarts the DRAC, not the whole server, so this is also a good hint, but well, not answers the question. I wanted to reset the iDrac *password* without rebooting. For example, just from Linux.
I said, it's a good hint, because after trying to log in some hundred times, the DRAC got unresponsive, so we had to reset i this way. But yeah, for resetting the password we had to restart the whole server.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who would be searching for solution. The tool you want to install on esx is called "Dell EMC iDRAC Tools for VMware"
available as vib from [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=g11xv&oscode=xi65&productcode=poweredge-r720)
it will e.g. show your drac IP, systemtag, add new drac admin all from esxcli

Comment: This supports 6.5 and 6.7.  Not 5.5-6.0.  OP is running 5.5.